# is it possible to save Generic <T: Decodable> callback in Dict or Array

Tags: swift, generics, decoder

I have a situation where I don't want to call the same APIs again. For that, I am saving callback in a dictionary And checking event time with URL(URL as key, callback is value).

When I try to use Generics callback in dict, it is not accepting with out type. Can anyone please let me know how to save it. I am unable to use it without specifying type.

Ex:
Here "T" is like my Students model.
From ClassA & ClassB I requested for Students list at the same-time/one-after-one. Now I will get the same response in both classes. I am calling Alamofire from APIManager class for all my API calls by using one single method, which is "request()". if I don't save callbacks in requesr() method, how can I send back students data to classA & ClassB by decoding.

I will remove the saved callback after sending data back to classes.

```
typealias requestCallback<T : Decodable> = (T?) -> Void

class APIManager {

  var totalRequest : [String : [requestCallback]] = [:] as! [String : [requestCallback]]
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to store a callback? This will work but I don't think it's what you want `class APIManager<T: Decodable> { var totalRequest : [String : [RequestCallback<T>]] = [:] }`

Comment: In my code, there is a chance of executing the same API calls multiple times. I don't want that. so I am saving callback with key-value pairs in a dict with url, and sending data to all classes by using callbacks from saved dict.

Comment: Yes I got that from your question but I don't understand why you want to save the callback rather than the data

Comment: I agree with Joakim that this is a very confusing use case. How would the calling code work? What would a consumer of `totalRequest` look like? Is this some kind of queuing system (so you'll just store these in a dictionary while the request is in flight, and then evaluate them all and remove them when the request completes)? It's not clear what "event time" means in this case. What type do you expect `totalRequest["..."]` to return? What would `T` be?

Comment: I edited my question. I am missing anything please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rolling your own, check out `NSURLCache`: https://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/

> Untold numbers of developers have hacked together an awkward, fragile system for network caching functionality, all because they weren’t aware that NSURLCache could be setup in two lines and do it 100× better. Even more developers have never known the benefits of network caching, and never attempted a solution, causing their apps to make untold numbers of unnecessary requests to the server.